# Three organic avacodo pits, two are one color, the third is another

Tags: growth

I have potted three organic avacodo pits and am wondering why two of them are growing tall,thin and red in color while the third is shorter with a thicker green stalk.

Comment: While I am sure all is fine, pictures would help us identify any specific problems.

Comment: As I did  a simple image search, I noticed a great variety in seedling foliage as well as the fruit of a mature tree. Did all the seedlings come from same cultivar? Grow in the same place. Cultivars are mostly hybrids, their seeds don't come true to parents.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you grow something from seed it will not grow true to type. Perhaps the odd looking one has genetics closer related to an earlier parent plant. It's not always a bad thing, sometimes you get something new and unique, sometimes you do get a throwback with less desirable genetics though. Good luck. I hope they come out well for you.